# How do Chebyshev inequality and Weak Law of Large Number translate into this?

Tags: probability, inequality, proof-explanation, law-of-large-numbers

The Chebyshev inequality states that if $X$ is a random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then:

$$\mathbf P\bigl(|X -\mu |\geq c\bigr)\leq\frac{\sigma^2}{c^2},~~~~\textrm{for all}~c > 0.$$

The Weak Law of Large numbers states that for $n$ independent identically distributed r.v.'s $X_i$:

$${\mathbf P\bigl(|M_n -\mu |\geq \epsilon\bigr) = \mathbf P\Bigl(\Bigl|\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n}-\mu\Bigr|\geq\epsilon\Bigr)\rightarrow 0,\textrm{ as}~n\rightarrow\infty.}$$

In a sample of $n$ independent identically distributed  r.v.'s $X_i$ with sample mean $M_ n=(X_1+\cdots +X_ n)/n$, it is said that the Chebyshev inequality gives us:

$$\mathbf{P}\big(|M_ n-\mu | \geq \epsilon \big)\leq\frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon ^2}.$$

Why is $n$ there in the denominator?  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's denote $S_{n} = \frac{X_{1}+\cdots + X_{n}}{n}$ and observe that is $X_{1},\cdots X_{n}$ (independent) have the same distribution of random variable $X$ (with second moment) $m = \mathbb{E}(\frac{S_{n}}{n})$.

Using Chebyshev with $\frac{S_{n}}{n}$ we get

$$\begin{cases}\mathbb{P}(|\frac{S_{n}}{n} - m|\geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}\cdot Var(\frac{S_{n}}{n}) \\ Var(\frac{S_{n}}{n}) = \frac{1}{n^{2}}\cdot Var(S_{n}) = \frac{1}{n^{2}}\cdot Var(X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}) = \frac{1}{n^{2}}\cdot nVar(X) \end{cases}$$

Which explains the $n$ in the denominator.

And we conclude with $0 \leq \mathbb{P}(|\frac{S_{n}}{n} - m|\geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{1}{n}\cdot Var(X) \underset{n \to \infty}{\longmapsto} 0$

Comment: Is there a name to that rule (the second point)?

Comment: I see, your second point explains how to get this:

$$\displaystyle\sigma_{\overline{x}}^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}.$$

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @muxo Which rule ? if you mean the second line of the system it follows directly from the properties of mean (linearity) and variance. For the first question you have just denoted $Var(X)$ and the random variables in an other way, if I understood your question, let me know.

Comment: Yes, I mean that second line.  It feels like something important, and I wonder if it has a name.

Comment: @muxo Follows from this property : $Var(\sum\limits_{1 \leq j \leq n}X_{j}) = \sum\limits_{1 \leq j \leq n}Var(X_{j}) + 2\sum\limits_{i<j}Cov(X_{i},X_{j})$ using that if the random variables are independant, $Cov(X_{i},X_{j}) = 0 \hspace{0.2cm} \forall \hspace{0.1cm} i,j$.

Comment: Thank you!!!  You've been great help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to page 2 this [paper](http://people.wku.edu/david.neal/382/sampling/Chebyshev.pdf), and $\overline{x}$ is the sample mean in a sample of size $n$:

$$\displaystyle\sigma_{\overline{x}}^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$$

In this case, $\overline{x} = M_n$.  Thus we have:

$$\mathbf{P}\big(|M_ n-\mu | \geq \epsilon \big)\leq\frac{\sigma_{\overline{x}}^2}{\epsilon ^2} = \frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon ^2}.$$

That explains the $n$ in the denominator.