# Coin tossing run convergence. Show that $P(\vert \frac{Y_n}{n}-2p(1-p)\vert \ge\epsilon) \to 0$

Tags: probability

A coin is tossed $n$-times. The probability of getting heads $H$ is $p\in(0,1)$. A run is defined  run as a maximum-length subsequence of equal values. For example, the sequence $\color{blue}{HHH}\color{green}{T} \color{purple}{HH}$ consists of three runs. Let $Y_n$ be the number of runs. Show that: $$P(\vert \frac{Y_n}{n}-2p(1-p)\vert \ge\epsilon) \to 0 \space \space \space \text{for} \space \space n\to\infty$$

Hint: Use the chebyshev inequality and write $Y_n$ using indicator functions.

**My thoughts/what I have done so far:**

First of all the Chebyshev inequality states that $$P(\vert X-\mu \vert \ge c )\le \frac{\sigma ^2}{c^2}$$

where $\mu$ is the mean and $\sigma^2$ the variance. I am not sure how to apply this inequality here though but I tried something assuming that the mean $\mu=E[X]$ of $\frac{Y_n}{n}$ is $2p(1-p)$.

$$P\left(\vert \frac{Y_n}{n}-2p(1-p)\vert \ge\epsilon\right)\le \frac{E\left[ \left(\frac{Y_n}{n}-2p(1-p) \right)^2 \right]}{\epsilon^2}$$

If I could show that the numerator goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity then I could show this statement is true. $$\frac{E\left[ \left(\frac{Y_n}{n}-2p(1-p) \right)^2 \right]}{\epsilon^2}=\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\left( E\left[ \frac{Y^2_n}{n^2}\right] \right)-\frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \left(E\left[2p(1-p) \right] \right)^2$$

Since the second experession is just the expected value of a number:

$$\implies \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\left( E\left[ \frac{Y^2_n}{n^2}\right] \right)-\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}(2p-2p^2)^2$$

This doesn't really seem right so I would appreciate any help/hints/solutions.

**A short off topic question:** Is it normal for these questions to feel very difficult and to not know where to start/what to do considering this is my first course in probability (6 weeks in)? I am kind of starting to doubt myself because I have never had so many difficulties understanding concepts in math.

**Edit:** Even though E-A has helped me a lot, I am still not quite sure how to finish the problem (see comments below E-A's answer) so any help is still welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let the sequence of coins be denoted $X_1, X_2, X_3, ...$ Note that $Y_n = 1+\sum_{i=2}^{n} 1_{X_i \neq X_{i-1}}$. (To see why, you can say that a round ends on turn $i-1$ if $i$ and $i-1$ don't match, and the $+1$ is the last run.) Can you finish from there?

As for your soft question, it is hard to establish what is normal and what is not. For a first course in probability though, if you have not taken real analysis, even just the idea of playing with epsilons and deltas should be really new, let alone stuff about different kinds of convergence, or what a random variable is (those are always hard). I left most of my final essentially blank for my first semester graduate level probability course, and through constant exposure, I got better (still a very long way to go). If you enjoy the flavor of problems, you should take more probability classes! I would advise you to not worry too much, but if you are concerned, I would talk to a human on your course staff. I am sure they would be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks for your hint and sorry for the late reply. I understand how the sum is a representation of $Y_n$ but I am not sure how I can show convergence in this case. I was thinking that the upper bound would occur when $X_i \not = X_{i-1} \space \forall X_i$ which would mean that the number of runs $n$ are: $$\max Y_n=1+n$$ For $n \to \infty$: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{Y_n}{n} =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}+\frac{n}{n}=1$$ Am I at least on the righ track?

Comment: Not really, maybe read this math.SE question and answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3634307/how-do-chebyshev-inequality-and-weak-law-of-large-number-translate-into-this?rq=1 and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: If I want to use the Weak law of large numbers (WLLN) here, I need to calculate the mean and variance of $Y_n$ which I don't know how to do. This is also the problem I had before and why I tried to somehow get around it by bounding it and seeing if that works.

Comment: If you look at the form for $Y_n$ I gave you, how can you calculate its variance? And no, you wont use WLLN here; I just sent that so that you know how people use Chebyshev with sums of variables.

Comment: I don't know. The Indicator function in the sum is really throwing me off and I am not sure what to do with it. Maybe I could rewrite the variance as $$Var(Y_n)=E[Y_n^2]-(E[Y_n])^2$$?

Comment: Yup, and now expand out the square of the sum.

Comment: $$Y_n^2=1+21+\sum_{i=2}^{n} 1_{X_i \neq X_{i-1}}+(\sum_{i=2}^{n} 1_{X_i \neq X_{i-1}})^2 \\ \implies E[Y_n^2]=E[1+21+\sum_{i=2}^{n} 1_{X_i \neq X_{i-1}}+(\sum_{i=2}^{n} 1_{X_i \neq X_{i-1}})^2 \\ =E[1]+E[2\sum_{i=2}^{n} 1_{X_i \neq X_{i-1}}]+E[(\sum_{i=2}^{n} 1_{X_i \neq X_{i-1}})^2]$$ Now I somehow need to figure out how to calculate the expected values. Small edit: Let me calculate the second term I think a few things might simplify.

Comment: The second term in the variance is: $$ (E[Y_n])^2 \\ = (E[1+\sum_{i=2}^n \mathbf 1_{X_i \not= X_{i-1}}])=(E[1]+E[\sum_{i=2}^n \mathbf 1_{X_i \not= X_{i-1}}]) \\ = 1+ 2E[\sum_{i=2}^n \mathbf 1_{X_i \not= X_{i-1}}]+ (E[\sum_{i=2}^n \mathbf 1_{X_i \not= X_{i-1}}])^2 $$. I can't edit the other comment but the "$21$" should just be a factor 2 in front of the sum.

Comment: Good work; keep going. You will need to expand out the square inside the expectation too. Then, finding expectations will come out to be looking at what can happen to $X_{i-1}, X_i, X_{i+1}$

Comment: Nice! Let me give it a try.

Comment: I am sort of stuck. As far as I can see the "$1$" and the cross terms "$2\sum_{j=2}^n \mathbf 1_{X_i \not= X_{i-1}}$" cancel and I am left with: $$E[\sum_{i=2}^n \sum_{j=2}^n \mathbf 1_{X_j \not= X_{j-1}}]-\left( E\left[ \sum_{i=2}^n\mathbf 1_{X_i \not= X_{i-1}}\right] \right)^2$$ I am not really sure how to continue here. At first I was thinking I can rewrite $$E[\sum \sum \ldots] \space \space \space\text{as}  \space  \space  \space E[\sum\ldots]E[\sum \ldots]$$ but then the variance would be zero.

Comment: Also, for the expected value, will I need to assign $1$ and $0$ to heads and tales for everything to make sense?